# Eliminating inferrable generic type parameters from extension methods

Tags: c#, .net, generics, automapper

I am using .NET mapping library AutoMapper in my application, and I have a generic extension method like this:

```
public static T2 Map<T1, T2>(this T1 o)
{
    return Mapper.Map<T1, T2>(o);
}

...

var nc = new NonCustomer();
Customer c = nc.Map<NonCustomer, Customer>();
```

Is there any way I can get rid of the `T1` generic parameter from the extension method so it is inferred? Resulting in a call like this:

```
var nc = new NonCustomer();
Customer c = nc.Map<Customer>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use generic version for T1 parameter.

You just need to change it to object:

```
public static TDest Map<TDest>(this object o)
{
    // todo check o is not null
    return (TDest) Mapper.Map(o, o.GetType(), typeof (TDest));
}
```

If you are using AutoMapper v2 and above, you could write it as following:

```
public static TDest Map<TDest>(this object o)
{
    return Mapper.Map<TDest>(o);
}
```

Comment: Then the method isn't so generic, is it?  You have to box value types to use it this way.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk AutoMapper will box it anyway https://github.com/jbogard/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/MappingEngine.cs#L95

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk: This solution brings the box issue, but to be honest, it does eliminate one generic parameter...it's a nice solution if T1 is always a class.

Comment: @hazzik Somebody should fix that.  It doesn't seem like there's any reason for the box.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way. Generic type inference doesn't work on return types. This kind of puts the usefulness of your extension method questionable. Why not directly working with the `.Map<TSource, TDest>` method?

Comment: Yeah if the return type cannot be inferred - then it does put the usefulness of the method in question! Thought I may have been missing something

Comment: No, you are not missing anything. Generic type inference could operate only on method input parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Great question. I've always been too lazy to answer it for myself but then the cobbler's children always get extension methods last...

You could make it a bit DRYer and arguably a touch prettier by side stepping the issue and doing one inference at a time:

```
public static MapperSource<T> Mapper(this T that)
{
    return new MapperSource<T>( that);
}

public class MapperSource<T>
{
    public T2 To<T2>
    {
        return Mapper.Map<T,T2>();
    }
}
```

Which allows you to:

```
var nc = new NonCustomer();
Customer c = nc.Mapper().To<Customer>();
```

A more common way (for me anyway) to consume those is to set up helpers for each `Mapper.CreateMap`'d route as follows:

```
public static Customer ToResult(this NonCustomer that)
{
    return that.Mapper().To<Customer>();
}
```

(Sadly because there are no Extension Properties, it can't get any prettier than this. Then again, it'll all be moot when we're all using F#)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, because there's no such thing as partial type inference in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Only when you remove the `T1` generic type altogether and write a specific method for `NonCustomer`:

```
public static T2 Map<T2>(this NonCustomer o)
{
    return Mapper.Map<NonCustomer, T2>(o);
}
```

Comment: Obviously this answer is correct! but why do I have a impulse to downvote?

Comment: @DannyChen: No idea. Why do you?

Comment: The reason why OP use generic T1 here is because he wants more types can be mapped. An extension method to `NonCustomer` only removes other mapping type possibility.